# Active Directory Knowledge Consistency Checker Not Creating Links Between Two Sites

Tags: windows, active-directory

I have 3 sites:

- Site A: 192.168.0.0/24
- Site B: 192.168.7.0/24
- Site C: 192.168.1.0/24

Each site has 1 domain controller:

- Site A: SERVER-1
- Site B: SERVER-2
- Site C: SERVER-3

In Active Directory Sites and Service, I see that connections were automatically generated as follows:

- Site A has two auto generated connections: From SERVER-2/Site B and From SERVER-3/Site C
- Site B has only one auto generated connection: From SERVER-1/Site A
- Site C has only one auto generated connection: From SERVER-1/Site A

Why did the KCC did not auto generate a Site B connection for From SERVER-3/Site C and a Site C connection for From SERVER-2/Site B?

Comment: the only explanation is the cost between B-C is greater than B-A-C. No matter what it is, try not to intervene KCC, just leave it alone.

Answer (score 1):

`How come KCC did not auto generate a Site B connection for From SERVER-3/Site C and a Site C connection for From SERVER-2/Site B?`

They aren't needed for a complete replication path for all hosts.

It isn't the job of the KCC to create a Site Link between every site. That would be a full mesh topology. It wouldn't scale to very many sites. The KCC checks every 15 minutes, and if a path does not exist, it is created dynamically, as you may confirm.

The selection of which Links are created can be influenced by Site Link cost.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/get-started/replication/active-directory-replication-concepts

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc755326(v=ws.10)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc755994(v=ws.10)

**Site Link Cost**

"The ISTG uses the cost settings on site links to determine the route of replication between three or more sites that replicate the same directory partition. The default cost value on a site link object is 100. You can assign lower or higher cost values to site links to favor inexpensive connections over expensive connections, respectively. Certain applications and services, such as domain controller Locator and DFS, also use site link cost information to locate nearest resources. For example, site link cost can be used to determine which domain controller is contacted by clients located in a site that does not include a domain controller for the specified domain. The client contacts the domain controller in a different site according to the site link that has the lowest cost assigned to it."

"Cost is usually assigned not only on the basis of the total bandwidth of the link, but also on the availability, latency, and monetary cost of the link. For example, a 128-kilobits per second (Kbps) permanent link might be assigned a lower cost than a dial-up 128-Kbps dual ISDN link because the dial-up ISDN link has replication latency-producing delay that occurs as the links are being established or removed. Furthermore, in this example, the permanent link might have a fixed monthly cost, whereas the ISDN line is charged according to actual usage. Because the company is paying up-front for the permanent link, the administrator might assign a lower cost to the permanent link to avoid the extra monetary cost of the ISDN connections."

**KCC and Topology Generation**

"Operating independently, the KCC on each domain controller uses its own view of the local replica of the configuration directory partition to arrive at the same intrasite topology. One KCC per site, the ISTG, determines the intersite replication topology for the site. Like the KCC that runs on each domain controller within a site, the instances of the ISTG in different sites do not communicate with each other. *They independently use the same algorithm to produce a consistent, well-formed spanning tree of connections.* Each site constructs its own part of the tree and, when all have run, a working replication topology exists across the enterprise."

"The predictability of all KCCs allows scalability by reducing communication requirements between KCC instances. All KCCs agree on where connections will be formed, *ensuring that redundant replication does not occur* and that all parts of the enterprise are connected."